# Displayfield size from fieldLabel to value

Tags: extjs

hello i am have this component in form and i am want edit size from fieldLabel to value, i want do it size small.

```
{
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            value: 'ABC',
            itemId: 'itemNumber',
            fieldLabel: 'Item Number'
        },
```

thanks)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Try adding the following 'labelWidth' to your config one like the below example

```
         {
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            value: 'ABC',
            itemId: 'itemNumber',
            fieldLabel: 'Item Number',
            labelWidth: // Give a width that suits your req
        }
```

Hope it helps you.